# Detecting deleted users while querying https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to know if the query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$select=` will return deleted users or not, if we keep looping with next links.

If yes, which attribute will help us figure out deleted users.
Looks like `deletedDateTime` comes null for all users.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it returns deleted users as `@removed` objects as shown below:

```
{
    "id": "587b87af-b07d-44ec-8ab7-10df65b5d535",
    "@removed": {
        "reason": "changed"
    }
},
{
    "id": "03ca4279-50fe-4b42-b3fd-ed01f30c973e",
    "@removed": {
        "reason": "deleted"
    }
}
```

The reason field indicates whether the user is soft deleted (i.e. "`changed`") or hard deleted (i.e. "`deleted`").